# How to check for the presence of an item in a Python tuple without encountering a ValueError?

Tags: python, python-2.7, indexing, tuples

For'ing over `tuples` consisting of `(spendCampaign, adset, adcontent)` (each value changing on each loop, I want to catch when the last item in the tuple is the same as the last item in a tuple in a saved mapping `oldAdMapping` (a tuple of tuples).

```
if adcontent == oldAdMapping[oldAdMapping.index((spendCampaign, adset, adcontent))][2]
```

I see now that this breaks down with a `ValueError` (and the equality check doesn't get executed) whenever any `(spendCampaign, adset, adcontent)` tuple does not actually exist in `oldAdMapping`.

For dicts, we have the `has_key()` function that allows us to check if something is a key in the dict while avoiding a `KeyError` if it's not. Is there something similar for tuples? If not, what's the best way of checking for the presence of an item in a tuple wuthout encountering a `ValueError`?

Comment: Start the `if` statement with `if (spendCampaign, adset, adcontent) in oldAdMapping and adcontent == oldAdMapping...` so that it checks for it first. If that first check doesn't succeed, it won't try to do anything else ("short-circuiting").

Answer (score 1):

You could validate if the tuple contains it:

```
if (spendCampaign, adset, adcontent) in oldAdMapping:
    index = oldAdMapping.index((spendCampaign, adset, adcontent))
```

And in your condition use `index`

```
if adcontent == oldAdMapping[index][2]:
    ...
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the `in` operator to see if a collection (tuple or list or similar) contains an object.

https://docs.python.org/release/2.7/library/stdtypes.html#sequence-types-str-unicode-list-tuple-buffer-xrange

Answer (score 0):

Put the code in a try except block and ignore the error:

```
try:
    if adcontent == oldAdMapping[oldAdMapping.index((spendCampaign, adset, adcontent))][2]:
        # do what you want here
except ValueError:
    pass
```